# Should I add COALESCE to all my <> comparisons?

Tags: t-sql, coalesce, null-coalescing-operator

After quite a while of running my script, I realized that the `<>` operator is not working as it should, or at least when `NULL` values are concerned. Many of my `MERGE` commands did not fall in the `UPDATE` block because `<>` did not detect two different values.

So for a few of my comparisons, I added `COALESCE`.

E.g. instead of

```
Value1 <> Value2
```

I used

```
COALESCE(Value1, '') <> COALESCE(Value2, '')
```

The question is whether it is safe to add `COALESCE` to all other ones or does this also depend on the data type or are there other caveats?

Comment: In this scenario I would use ISNULL in stead of COALESCE because there are only values (the field and the default value). But keep in mind that you default the NULL to '', which means that is Value1 = NULL and Value2 = '' they are considered equal

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this scenario `IS NULL` is a better choice, but also I will make sure that those values are nullable, to begin with.

Comment: Differences between `Coalesce` and `IsNull` are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#comparing-coalesce-and-isnull). `Coalesce` is standard SQL and can handle more than two parameters. As noted by Luc, you are introducing a _magic value_ rather than making a precise comparison, i.e. `Value1 != Value2 or ( Value1 is NULL and Value2 is not NULL ) or ( Value1 is not NULL and Value2 is NULL )`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the coalesces like that so long as your system considers NULLs and zero-length strings to be equivalent, i.e.: NULL = ''

If you have a huge list of comparisons in your merge statement you might try just replacing it with an EXCEPT set operator

```
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (SELECT SRC.* EXCEPT SELECT TGT.*) THEN
   UPDATE ...
```

a NULL value compared to a NULL is unknown, but in set-based operations they look for distinctness: NULL is distinct from non-nulls but NULL is not distinct from another NULL.

If the SRC row and TGT row are identical it will return an empty set thus skipping the update.

Answer (score 0):

The `COALESCE` command, should be used when the data can be `NULL`, like you're not using inner join or the column allows for null values. For my personal opinion: don't force the system to make unnecessary instructions, if you could avoid them.

For SQL `NULL` and `NULL` are unknown values, they can't be equal nor different. See example:

```
declare @vA int
declare @vB int

select @vA, @vB, iif(@vA = @vB, 1, 0), iif(@vA <> @vB, 1, 0)
```

Comment: So best to use them if the column is nullable, am I right?

Comment: Or you're doing a left outer join, right outer join or full outer join.